# How can I replace &amp; with an ampersand in my database?

Tags: mysql

I have about 6k rows of data where we have `&amp;` in various different rows. I'd like to replace this with an ampersand sign if possible. Can someone please tell me how to do this with mysql?  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **[MySQL REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)** function should work nicely:

```
UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = REPLACE(fieldname, "&amp;", "&");
```

Comment: Hi gahooa, I think that won't work because if there is something &amp; something, your code will match the &amp; and replace everything with an ampersand. I just want to change the &amp; to & between the words.

Comment: Am I wrong or will this do what I need? I just don't want to make a mistake here. :)